# Maintain underscore separators' positions when printing f-string

Tags: python, string-formatting

If I have an amount like $40,000.00 I might want to make this more readable in code by [writing the number with underscore separators](https://peps.python.org/pep-0515/)

```py
deposit = 40_000_00
```

I know I can use the following syntactic sugar for formatting f-strings but this prints a thousands-separated integer (`4_000_000`)

```py
print(f"{deposit:_}")
# 4_000_000
```

Are the underscores that annotate the integer stored at any point for downstream use, or would I simply need to use an appropriate class with a `__repr__` to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: The underscores are not stored. They are allowed when making integer literals more readable but otherwise ignored

Comment: I pretty sure you can't. Python almost certainly doesn't keep track of those. From the doc: "*The underscores have no semantic meaning, and literals are parsed as if the underscores were absent.*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible. As detailed in the [PEP515](https://peps.python.org/pep-0515/) that you cited:

> The underscores have no semantic meaning, and literals are **parsed as if the underscores were absent**.

Thus the resulting python object has no knowledge that those underscores where ever there.

If you need to store a custom separator, be explicit. Use a string.

```
deposit = '40_000_00'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Are the underscores that annotate the integer stored at any point for downstream use

No, they're purely a syntactic convenience.

You should just format your values using a real formatter:

```py
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL , 'en_CA') # E.g. for Canada

print(locale.format_string('%d', 1234567, grouping=True)) # 1,234,567
```

As a bonus, it can be made it be correct of the user's locale (e.g. many places use spaces for separators in stead of commans, and commas instead of the period for the decimal point).

Comment: Note that OP does **not** want a grouped thousands separator, but rather a separator at arbitrary positions ;)